# How to create service builder for liferay plugin project with maven

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide, liferay-service-builder

I have Already create Liferay Plugin project. and maven install also over.
it gives

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:29.773s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 17 15:46:10 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/151M
[INFO] -----------------------------.
```

But unable to add service builder.

When i try to add service builder
new->Liferay service builder.

It does not showing any plugin project.
  Then how to add service builder?

Comment: Please take a look here:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/maven
That is the official Documentation on Liferay Maven development. I think you shouldn't go the new -> Liferay Service  way, but use the maven way. To be honest, I am not that into the Maven build process, but I think there should be hints in the official Documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly speaking Liferay-Maven combination is not so fully supported by Liferay IDE in eclipse. Originally Liferay IDE has been created for only ANT support but since maven support has been introduced there are many things missing.

This issue which you have raised is same for following options as well.

1. JSF Portlet
2. Layout
3. Theme
4. Service Builder

This is not an issue for following options

1. Hook
2. Portlet
3. Vaadin Portlet

So, best way is to generate new service builder through maven archetypes supported for specific liferay version.
E.g com.liferay.maven.archetypes:liferay-servicebuilder-archetype:6.2.1 for liferay 6.2.1 GA2 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a vaadin application to existing liferay portlet then create new LIFERAY-VAADIN project and there you can use "You can continue to use ServiceBuilder as you always have, and retrieve data from your services using XXXXXServiceUtil (or XXXXXLocalServiceUtil)." You may also want to check [here](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/update-on-vaadin-liferay-integration), and [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13083421).

For example here is one *DatabaseUtil* class from vaadin.

```java
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.vaadin.data.util.HierarchicalContainer;

public class DatabaseUtil {
  public static HierarchicalContainer fillTree_db() {
    HierarchicalContainer container = new HierarchicalContainer();
    ArrayList < ArrayList < String >> treeNodes = new ArrayList < ArrayList < String >> ();

    try {

      List < TREEVIEW > nodes = TREEVIEWLocalServiceUtil.getAllNodes();

      for (TREEVIEW node: nodes) {
        String nodename = node.getNodename();
        ArrayList < String > row = new ArrayList < String > ();
        row.add(String.valueOf(node.getNodeid()));
        row.add(node.getNodename());
        row.add(String.valueOf(node.getRootid()));
        container.addItem(nodename);
        treeNodes.add(row);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < treeNodes.size(); i++) {
        int root = 0;
        root = Integer.parseInt(treeNodes.get(i).get(2));

        if (root != 0)
          container.setParent(treeNodes.get(i).get(1),
            treeNodes.get(root - 1).get(1));
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {}
    return container;
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I am new to liferay and i need service builder only. what is diff between liferay plugin project and LIFERAY-VAADIN ?

Comment: **Liferay plugin** project means if you are creating a new liferay plugin project. You can do so by launching Eclipse with Liferay IDE installed.
Just setup Liferay SDK and Server and go to File> New> Liferay Plugin Project

**LIFERAY-VAADIN** means if you want to create vaadin applicaiton on the top of liferay CMS.